# Проверка наличия интернет соединения

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

Как можно проверить наличие интернет соединения через java...?
Нижно чтобы при отсутствии интернета приложение вывело отдельно подготовленый .xml екран...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isNetworkAvailable activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
```

также необходимо добавить `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` в манифест.